# Java Selenium Get Url with Special Character

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to get a url using selenium-java 3.3.1 and when I do the following:

```
driver.get(url.toString())
```

Where the URL looks like this:

```
https://hello.world.io/@snapshot/web/1.23.207-1-gc2b81d1/?referrer=/beta
```

Selenium only enters everything after the `@` into the url of my ChromeBrowser.  I've tried URLEncoding the entire URL and only the portion after and containing the `@` but that gives me an invalid url error.

Would appreciate and help trying to force selenium-java to navigate to that url.

EDIT

I tried doing

```
driver.get("https://hello.world.io/@snapshot/web/1.23.207-1-gc2b81d1/?referrer=/beta");
```

and that works.

But I need to pass in the URL as a variable which I'm doing and then calling `.toString()`.  I've printed the result to toString() out to the console and it looks fine so there must be something very odd happening that I can put my finger on.

Comment: Putting that url in manually worked for me. So, doing this worked:   `driver.get("https://hello.world.io/@snapshot/web/1.23.207-1-gc2b81d1/?referrer=/beta");` I am guessing there is an issue with your `toString()` method

Comment: have you tried using driver.get(url) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Though I wasn't able to access the url of your concern `https://hello.world.io/@snapshot/web/1.23.207-1-gc2b81d1/?referrer=/beta` but using Selenium 3.4.0, chromedriver v2.29 & Google Chrome 58.x I have tried the following Usecases:

### Usecase 1:

If the concerned url `https://hello.world.io/@snapshot/web/1.23.207-1-gc2b81d1/?referrer=/beta` is a `Sting` class object, the following code works-

```
String url = "https://hello.world.io/@snapshot/web/1.23.207-1-gc2b81d1/?referrer=/beta";
driver.get(url);
```

### Usecase 2:

If the concerned url `https://hello.world.io/@snapshot/web/1.23.207-1-gc2b81d1/?referrer=/beta` is a `URL` class object, in that case you have to convert it from `URL` class to `String` class through `toString()` method as follows which worked for me too:

```
String url = "https://hello.world.io/@snapshot/web/1.23.207-1-gc2b81d1/?referrer=/beta";
URL myurl = new URL(url);
driver.get(myurl.toString());
```

> **PS**: If you are using the `URL` class you have to `import java.net.URL;` which will throws `MalformedURLException`, so you have to `import java.net.MalformedURLException;`

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: **usecase 2** is very similar to what I have in my own code base, but what I'm experiencing that that when I call driver.get(myurl.toString()) it only enters the portion of the string after the `@` symbol.